# Performance of put() in LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, queue, put

I am working on a stock trading application whose *key* feature is to accept some data from another system as fast as possible ( without blocking ). My application will then process the data at a later time.

So what I though was to let the messages queue in LinkedBlockingQueue/LinkedTransferQueue and then periodically drain the queue and process the data in a background thread.

So something along the lines of:

```
    private final LinkedTransferQueue<Data> queue = new LinkedTransferQueue<Data>();

    public void store( int index, long time, String[] data ) throws InterruptedException{
       Data data = new Data( index, time, data );
       queue.put( data );
    }

    private class BackgroundProcessor implements Runnable{

    private List<Data> entryList = new LinkedList<Data>( );

    @Override
    public void run(){

        try {
            while ( keepProcessing ){

                int count = queue.drainTo( entryList );

                for ( Data data : entryList ){
                //process data
                }
            }
        } catch( Exception e ){
               logger.error("Exception while processing data.", e);
        } 
    }

}
```

I then wanted to test the performance of this approach:

```
    public void testStore( String[] dataArray ) throws InterruptedException{

        int size = 100 * 1000;

        long iTime = System.nanoTime();
        for ( int i=0; i < size; i++ ){
           store( i, System.nanoTime, dataArray );
        }
        long fTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.err.println("Average Time (nanos): " +   (fTime - iTime)/size;

        float avgTimeInMicros = ((float) (fTime - iTime)/(size * 1000));
        System.err.println("Average Time (micros): " + avgTimeInMicros);
    }
```

I see that in my testStore(), if size = 100,0000, I can create the Data object ( which is an immutable object) and enqueue in 0.8 micro-second. However, if I decrease the size to 50, it takes as much as 20 micros.

I am assuming, the jvm after a while optimizes my code.
However, in my application, getting 50 data messages in a burst is more realistic, is there a way to tune the jvm ( or my code ) to enqueue in 1-2 micros regardless of the burst size?

P.S I tried this test on jdk 1.6 with -mx == -ms 512m.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are timing the performance, but make sure that before you start timing you have "primed the pump" - meaning that there is time lost when JVM first loads new classes. This class loading time will be significant in proportion to measuring just a small number of messages. I would make the test run about 1,000 iterations - then simulate your burst of 50 messages. This would ensure your results are not skewed by JVM start-up/class loading. In general, ensuring constant performance time for intermittent processing in Java is a challenging task.

Comment: Totally agree with the above comment. Yours is a naive micro-benchmark. Have a look at this must-read article by Goetz: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I now warm up the queue before any real data is inserted. Consequently, a subsequent burst of 50 messages is enqueued in about ~2 micros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process 10,000 and then test for bursts of 50 after the JVM has warmed up.  For a trading system, you would ensure the JVM is warmed up before you start trading.

If you want your trading system to be consistently fast, you could consider how it can be done without discarding any objects.

You might find the Disruptor library interesting.  It is designed to handle 5 M messages/second or more. http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/

Comment: Hi Peter, I have looked at the disruptor library and its fantastic, although it might be an overkill for my particular job. Do you know if it has a way to not hold the producers? ( I know they have different variants of "ClaimStrategy" where one can select the flavor of waiting (lock, spin etc ..). Cheers.

Comment: The problem with not holding the producer is having to allow the queue grow efficiently.  Often the cost of a large queue out weighs the benefits.  The way I get around this is to use shared memory which can grow to as large as the disk space.  If you have a fast disk (e.g. SSD) you can be millions of message behind with minimal impact.